# Writing a javascript program with simple for loop

Tags: javascript

I have to write a javascript program that will ask the amount of groceries I want and then loop that loops that number and asks for the price each time and keeps a counter of how many. Ive tried many times but the loop does not seem to be looping. I cannot continue until I get this sorted out. Heres my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Grocery Store calculator</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <script>

            var userEntry = prompt("How many grocery items would you like to add?");
            if (userEntry == parseInt(userEntry));

            else
            {
                alert("Please enter a valid integer!");
                prompt("How many grocery items would you like to add?");
            }

            for( n = 0; n < userEntry.length; n++);
            {
                var price = parseInt (prompt("Enter cost of item. "));
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Your handling of invalid user input is a bit off, right now it is not assigning userEntry to the result of the second prompt (or parsing the input).  It will also only ask for a valid integer once, ignoring further bad input.  You probably want to take input from the user in a while loop, and continue looping until a proper number is given.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
for( n = 0; n < userEntry.length; n++);
```

To:

```
for( n = 0; n < userEntry; n++)
```

`userEntry` is your length it is an integer...

Also get rid of the `;`'s after:

```
if (userEntry == parseInt(userEntry));
```

and

```
for( n = 0; n < userEntry.length; n++);
```

Answer (score 1):

Too many syntax errors!! Use browser element inspector and go to the "console" tab to see what JS errors you have. http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs132/resources/inspector/

Your if block is totally incorrect. It needs to have an opening and closing curly brackets just like your else part instead of a semicolon at the end. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

On your else block, you need to store the user's answer in the "userEntry" variable:

```
userEntry = prompt("How many grocery items would you like to add?");
```

On you for loop, you have not defined the variable 'n': http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

once you get all that fixed, then you can create a new variable, let's say called "totalPrice" just before the for loop then keep on adding the cost of each item to that variable:

```
// before for loop
var totalPrice = 0;
// inside the loop after the prompt
totalPrice = totalPrice + price;
```

Hope this helps. Please learn the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 for( n = 0; n < userEntry.length; n++);
            {
                var price = parseInt (prompt("Enter cost of item. "));
            }
```

to

```
 for(var n = 0; n < userEntry; n++)
            {
                var price = parseInt (prompt("Enter cost of item. "));
            }
```

1. missing var *(optional)*
2. userEntry is your length
3. ";" at the end is wrong